# Why does console.log wrongly print an empty array?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console.log

I use Firefox.

This code logs `[]`.

```
var log = console.log;

function new_comb(aComb) {
    var res = [];
    log(aComb); // <- This is the line
    for (var p in aComb) {
        var peg = aComb[p];
        var current = peg[peg.length - 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < aComb.length; i++) {
            if (i == p) continue;
            if (current > aComb[i][aComb[i].length - 1]) continue;
            var tmp = aComb.splice(0);
            tmp[i].push(current);
            tmp[p].pop();
            res.push(tmp);
        }
    }
    return res;
}

var comb = [
    [3, 1],
    [9, 2],
    [15, 0]];
var res = new_comb(comb);
```

This code logs the correct value.

```
var log = console.log;

function new_comb(aComb) {
    var res = [];
    log(aComb); // <- This is the line
    // note that I comment this out.
    /*for (var p in aComb) {
        var peg = aComb[p];
        var current = peg[peg.length - 1];
        for (var i = 0; i < aComb.length; i++) {
            if (i == p) continue;
            if (current > aComb[i][aComb[i].length - 1]) continue;
            var tmp = aComb.splice(0);
            tmp[i].push(current);
            tmp[p].pop();
            res.push(tmp);
        }
    }*/
    return res;
}

var comb = [
    [3, 1],
    [9, 2],
    [15, 0]];
var res = new_comb(comb);
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Not your question, but you should prefer something like `var log = console.log.bind(console);` to keep context

Comment: Or better yet, with `console.log` or any other host-provided function: `function log(msg) { return console.log(msg); }` Host-provided functions can be (and are allowed to be) very squirrelly indeed. They're not guaranteed to have `bind`, and they're not guaranteed to work correctly when called via other references than their normative one.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, What are host provided functions?

Comment: @learner: Anything you don't see in [the JavaScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/). So `console`'s various functions, `alert`, `prompt`, `confirm`, all the DOM functions, ...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`console.log` shows *live* data, not a snapshot of the object at the time you run it.

Since you `splice` all the data out of the array, it is empty almost as soon as you log it.

Stringify or deep copy the array if you want to log a snapshot of it.

Comment: +1 Better wording and fully explained in 30 seconds less than my answer. :)

Comment: I now realize I wanted to use `slice` and not `splice` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you log objects in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox, what you get logged on the console is a reference to the object, which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at the moment in time you call `console.log()`, but it is the value of the object at the moment you open the console.